# Html Report generation for test scripts

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, cmd

I have already imported `HtmlTestRunner` module in my test scripts and executing test scripts through command line.
But, it gives me following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 6, in <module>
    import HtmlTestRunner
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HtmlTestRunner'
```

I even provided the report directory path inside :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
        output='C:/Users/Anjali/PycharmProjects/Selenium-Framework/DemoProject/POMProjectDemo/reports'))
```

Can anyone help me with where I'm making mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to replace forward slash with backslash**

```
  if __name__=='__main__':
        unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HtmlTestRunner
           (output='C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Selenium_Python\Selenium-with- 
            Python\Reports'))
```